# I am using FCM.how can i display notification tittle in alert dialogue or custom Toast when app is in foreground rather than on status bar?

Tags: android

Right now i am using this when app is in foreground it gives me status on status bar now i want alert dialogue r custom popup for notification when appp is in foreground

```
    if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message

            try
            {
                Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
                pushNotification.putExtra("message", title);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new  NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.imgpsh_fullsize)
                        .setContentTitle(title);
                NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)     getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                manager.notify(0, builder.build());

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: You can call a function/method of your Activity when the app is in the foreground, you can use the broadcast receiver to initiate the method inside you Activity.

Comment: i use this in main activity  but   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                    // checking for type intent filter
                    if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION)) {
                        // new push notification is received

                    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message"); it gives me null whats the issue ? why my broad cast is not calling

Comment: Yes, you can broadcast the message to the main activity and if the activity is open then you can display you toast/dialog there

Comment: create a different method in your main Activity and then pass data in it, if you need I can write an answer for the work you need

Comment: Kindly send me code becouse broadcast reciever on recieved method is not called fro my main activity dnt know why

Comment: Check the answer, did that work for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy if your check for app is in the foreground is correct..
instead of displaying notification just create alert dialog having title and all required field as per your need and show it...

```java
if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
       
try {

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)

                    .setTitle("Your title")

                    .setMessage("Your messae")

                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();\

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


//here click of negative button is not added but you can add as per your need...
```

Please ask if any doubt again...

put above in some method say `showAlertMessage()` and call method from handler like this

```
Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                showAlertMessage();

            }
        });
```

Comment: it gives me error and go to exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: please refer above code once again i edited the same,for anything let me know further...i think that will help you

Comment: Thanxs it works for Toast Notifications but Not alert dialogue it gives me errorr of theme of my activity

Comment: Please google it for the same you will find the answer and if not please post your error to help you again..

Answer (score 0):

In your FCM class where you are getting the Notification add this

```
                 if (Activity.isVisible) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("notification");
                    //you can pass data using bundle here 
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
                }
```

> Activity is the name of your Activity and isVisible is the boolean
>   value. You need to set the isVisible value to true when the activity is in foreground else set it to false.

In your Activity add the below code

```
/**
     * Broadcast Receiver for updating the notification count when a notification is received
     */
    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            try {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {


                       //Add Dialog code here


                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        isVisible = true;
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("notification"));

    }

 @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
        isVisible = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
        isVisible = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
        isVisible = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
        isVisible = false;
    }
```

Try this and let me know if this work for you.

**P.S.** : This code is of Fragment you can convert it accordingly with respect to your Activity